# Best Ways to Archive Files in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, archive

We have a single Document Library that has thousands of files.
Some of the files are used on the daily basis.
Some of the files are not really used but we dont want to delete them, we still want them on the SharePoint.

I was wondering what would be the best approach to archive files having in mind that we still want to be able to find the " not daily used files"  using the search bar.

Any Suggestions is more than welcomed

Comment: Hi. I was wondering if you managed to find a solution or just changed the way you used the SPO to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint document library can store 30 million files and folders without any problem. You will have to create appropriate folder structures to store the files so that none of them crosses the 5000 list view threshold limitation and you are still able to open the document library and use the associated search box. This is the best option, since, if you use this with modern list experience then the search box in the upper left corner in the modern document library will show you items from all the subfolders under the current folder.

Or, you can create appropriate indexed columns and use them to create filtered views in your document library. In this way, you should be able to see your 'daily used files' whenever you open the document library by default. Now, to find the 'not daily used files', you will have to use SharePoint search (unless you use one of the filtered columns and create your custom view, like, show all items created between 2 dates, which will use 'created' column as filter and you need to create index on that column).

If you are using SharePoint search, then it is possible to indicate a specific document library to show results for. There shouldn't be any performance issues if you use SharePoint search, only the content might take some time to get indexed.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to simply set up a separate library, potentially on it's own site. Then, create a process that runs each night/weekend that looks for files that meets certain criteria and moves them there.

Option 2: add a custom field to the library which stores the document status, such as "archive". Configure the default views to not display items with a status of archive. With this system, the document remain where they are, but are hidden for normal use. They still show up in search, and a user could switch to a different view that shows archive items.

However, the end result of both of the above will be an ever increasing library with old content. A better approach might be to create a new site for each new initiative, and when the initiative is complete, part of the wrap up process would be to close the site down. This could mean simply switching people's permissions, or it could mean identifying quality documents and copying them out of the site into a different site, and then deleting that site.

Comment: Our concern is that  having a huge librarz with daily used files and other files that are rarely used  makes the process quite slow. Having a big library really slows things down and when a search is done it only show 800 items